# Create animation from TextureAtlas - libgdx

Tags: animation, libgdx, textures, texture-atlas

I have a .png file conataining a few textures one ofter one. I want to create an animation from this file.

I know how to create an animation from a TexturePacker .txt file but in this case it doesn't help me much.

Comment: Are the frames have the same size? Like [this spritesheet](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/gamedev/uploads/2013/11/spritesheet.png).

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what it is.

Answer (score 3):

libGDX wiki has a page on this topic: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

Comment: There's nothing about TextureAtlas in that tutorial.

Comment: @HerbMeehan You can obtain TextureRegions from TextureAtlas and then the rest of the tutorial will work.

Comment: @HerbMeehan Now, there dose has something about `TextureAtlas `.